# Can our brain access other dimensions/universes?

Tags: universe, brain

Following the Multiverse theory and a possibility that multiverses do not differ much when compared with one another, can we explain a person accessing thoughts or vision from a different multiverse? For example through dreams or being in an inebriated/drunken state?

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/27877/brain-connection-in-an-alternative-universe?rq=1

Comment: Mike from vsauce here - but where is here and can we be sure our universe is not just accessed through mind? After all it's just your mind telling you that you see, hear, taste and touch different things.

Comment: Are you asking about a concrete problem (which I am missing) or just seeding some speculation (which is off topic here)?

Comment: If you could, how would you even notice that? We lack the ability to even detect you entering another dimension in your dreams or thoughts. For all we know we could do it constantly without us knowing, but there is no reason to make that assumption because we don't know the difference between a dream in this or in another dimension. I would start establishing what any of this means before trying to explain it

Comment: The reason I cast the final VTC as unclear is that I can't tell if you're asking for an actual explanation (only valid answer: no, we can't explain it because we can't prove the theory) or help deriving an in-universe method (given that the theory is true and given that we could, what possible conditions in life as we know it today might be used as the vehicle for this communication?).  Please note that you're question is only on hold and can be easily reopened.  You need only edit your question to clarify your intent.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that any answer that could prove this to be true would likely win a Noble Prize. While we have some fantastic users on this site, which are great at giving accurate and thought provoking answers often getting evidence from all corners of the internet... i feel it may still be a bit far for them to stretch.

But if Handwavium is acceptable then you've already answered your own question. when you dream you see snippets from other universes. do you need more than that?

If so... Delta waves are the slowest and highest amplitude brain waves. ... This stage is also, associated with a unique brain wave pattern, in that during REM (Rapid eye movement) sleep, a sleepers brain waves demonstrate characteristics that are similar to waking sleep, a combination of alpha, beta, and desynchronous waves. perhaps the high amplitude of the waves allow the human brain to cross the multiverse barrier?

Answer (score 1):

Stated that we are following the Multiverse theory then **yes**, not only it's possible, **it has to be true for some *verses**.

It's basically a tautology, nevertheless it's prefectly valid for the multiverses.

How can this be achieved? There are undreds ideas in books, comics and film. Since multiverses are a pure speculation (so far) you should just choose the one you prefer, no one can say anything to falsify your concept.

Comment: Ooooooh... +1 for pointing out that the problem is already solved per the theory.  Now, are we one of those universes or not?  That's the problem.